# Tableau Server can't be restarted after error state

Tags: linux, tableau-api

My Tableau Server is degraded and using the following commands does not work:

- tsm start
- tsm stop
- tsm restart

I've already reset the machine a couple of times

tsm status:

Status: DEGRADED

'Tableau Server Gateway 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Application Server 0' is running.

'Tableau Server VizQL Server 0' is in an error state.

'Tableau Server Cache Server 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Coordination Service 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Cluster Controller 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Search And Browse 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Backgrounder 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Data Server 0' is in an error state.

'Tableau Server Data Engine 0' is running.

'Tableau Server File Store 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Repository 0' is stopped.

'Tableau Server Administration Agent 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Administration Controller 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Service Manager 0' is running.

'Tableau Server License Manager 0' is running.

'Tableau Server Database Maintenance 0' is stopped.

'Tableau Server Backup/Restore 0' is in an error state.

'Tableau Server Site Import/Export 0' is stopped.

'Tableau Server SAML Service 0' is stopped.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I highly recommend opening a support ticket and asking for assistance from Tableau Support directly